# Loading Contents into TextBox in WP8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to update the data on my server.

- I need to `GET` the data
- And need to store it in a TextBox
- Then I need to perform my Update operation.

I'm able to `GET` the data from server but unable to display it in the text box

**MY in XAML code:**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,157,12,4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,67,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txt_name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="PersonalFullName"/>
</Grid>
```

**My code to retrieve data from server on page load:**

```
private async void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String OrganizationResult;
    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("selectedItem"))
    {
        OrganizationResult = NavigationContext.QueryString["selectedItem"];
        string[] content = OrganizationResult.Split(',');
        string value = content[0];
        String id = value.Replace("{ id = ", "");
        Organization[] org;
        org = await client.searchOrganizationdetails(id);

        if (org != null)
        {
            var query = from c in org
                        select new
                        {
                            // Need to display the contents in textbox
                            // Eg:txt_name.Text=c.name
                        };
        }
    }
}
```

**My sample JSON data:**

[image]

Comment: what type does the variable "org"hold, you need to add some some sample data

Comment: and provide some sample json, eg { "person" : { "name" : "person name" }}, You will need to deserialize your data with a deserializer eg dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(org); name = json.person.name;

Comment: i had Deserialize it.. i need to bind that data into text box.. binding data in to text box is my problem..

Comment: what is the type of the deserializer object?

Comment: json is the object type

Comment: and is Organization the wrapper class to catch the Response?

Comment: yes.. its wrapper class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to bind to a list

Assuming you collection is of the type

```
public class Organization
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Your xaml should look like

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstOrganisations">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Address}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Bind with

lstOrganisations.ItemSource = org;

Comment: if i need to add new data name and address.. is it fine to move with your code..? i mean the same code structure can be used for adding new data..

Comment: For adding new data, you just need a textbox and a button which should not be in a list box.

Comment: thank-you..in developing WP8 application then we need to design seperate screen for Adding/Updating data..?

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be **inside** the LINQ query?I don't think you can do that...

Comment: I'm not particullary used to XAML or WPF,but i think you have to **bind** the value in the TextBox because its inside a Grid and the value changes depending on the row.

Comment: need to to use list..?

Comment: The json you just posted looks like data for a single entity to me.