# use of same screen for ADDING/UPDATING data in WP8..?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have a doubt, that

1.I had designed a page for adding Organization 
2.I can add the data and post it successfully to the server..
3.in turn i need to update my organization details.. 
so i need to use the same design page of adding organization to update my details,is it possible to use the same page or need to design other page to update the details..

so please suggest me what to do..

My Xaml Design Code..

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,157,12,4" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,67,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_name"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="PersonalFullName"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,115,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_address"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="78" Margin="121,110,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="PostalAddress"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="20,197,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="City" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txt_city"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="73" Margin="121,178,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="315" BorderThickness="0" InputScope="AddressCity"/>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to make 2 pages.
Just 
Send query strings from the respective pages where from the functionality of add and update is called And make the navigations like this

Navigating for adding details

```
string paramAdd="Add"
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/AddDetails.xaml?parameter="+paramAdd,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
```

Navigating for Updating details

```
string paramUpdate="Update"
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/Page/AddDetails.xaml?parameter="+paramUpdate,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
```

No make the page's OnNavigatedTo Event and in that write these lines of code.

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("parameter"))
            {
                string function= (NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"]).ToString();
                if(function=="Add")
                {
                    //Action for add
                }
               else if(function=="Update")
               {
                   //Action for update.
               }
            }
```

Hope this works, As it worked for me.

Comment: anyway you can. Just there must be the difference between both the parameter values so that we can differentiate the functions accordingly.

Comment: can you please see this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420768/loading-contents-into-textbox-in-wp8   this is my main problem in  updating content..